# How to capture "history records" using entry.OriginalValues on EntityState.Deleted

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-6

I am currently developing a data history repository based on EF since I did not want to use triggers acting on INSERT, DELETE, etc and capture all CRUD operations in code using EF6. However, when a record is **deleted**, and I am using the entry.OriginalValues collection and its PropertyNames, the app throws an exception. {"CurrentValues cannot be used for entities in the Deleted state."}

Using entry.OriginalValues on state **MODIFIED** and state **ADD** works just fine. How can I use OriginalValues when deleting?

Note: Hopefully the above/below makes sense regarding the problem at hand and thanks.

Here a snippet from my case statement:

```
switch( entry.State )
{
    case EntityState.Deleted:
    entry.OriginalValues
    .PropertyNames
    .Where( p => !ignore.Contains( p ) ) 
     //"ignore" is a list of fields not to worry about.
    .ToList()
        .ForEach( p =>
        HistoryList.Add( new History
        {
            Field1 = Value1,
            Field2 = Value2,

           ...  
         }
       )
     };
     break;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your example is missing a piece of code... The part you use "CurrentValues" in your delete logic which throw the exception.

**Disclaimer**: I'm the owner of the project EF+ (EntityFramework Plus) on [GitHub](http://entityframework-plus.net/)

Instead to make your own solution, you can use **EF+ Audit** which allow to easily track changes, exclude/include entity or property and auto save audit entries in the database.

If you don't want use the library, all the source code is available to answer almost all kind of questions you could have about auditing.

```
// using Z.EntityFramework.Plus; // Don't forget to include this.

var ctx = new EntityContext();
// ... ctx changes ...

var audit = new Audit();
audit.CreatedBy = "ZZZ Projects"; // Optional
ctx.SaveChanges(audit);

// Access to all auditing information
var entries = audit.Entries;
foreach(var entry in entries)
{
    foreach(var property in entry.Properties)
    {
    }
}
```

Project: http://entityframework-plus.net/

Documentation: [Entity Framework Audit Trail Context and Track Change](http://entityframework-plus.net/audit)

**Edit:** Answer comment question

Yes your code could be used.

This is exactly what the SaveChangesAsync overload do:

```
public static async Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(this DbContext context, Audit audit, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    audit.PreSaveChanges(context);
    var rowAffecteds = await context.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
    audit.PostSaveChanges();

    if (audit.CurrentOrDefaultConfiguration.AutoSavePreAction != null)
    {
        audit.CurrentOrDefaultConfiguration.AutoSavePreAction(context, audit);
        await context.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }

    return rowAffecteds;
}
```

**EDIT: Answer sub-question**

> Hi Jonathan, What are PreSaveChanges and PostSaveChanges

### PreSaveChanges

[Source Code](https://github.com/zzzprojects/EntityFramework-Plus/blob/master/src/shared/Z.EF.Plus.Audit.Shared/Audit/PreSaveChanges.cs)

This method will get all possible value before the save happen. By example, deleted value.

This method is a m

### PostSaveChanges

[Source Code](https://github.com/zzzprojects/EntityFramework-Plus/blob/master/src/shared/Z.EF.Plus.Audit.Shared/Audit/PostSaveChanges.cs)

This method basically gets some value that was impossible to take before saving changes. By example the identity value inserted in the database.

Comment: Jonathan, I looked at your EF+ code and wondered if the following could be used with logging deleted data. var audit = new Audit();
        audit.PreSaveChanges(this);
        var rowAffecteds = await base.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
        audit.PostSaveChanges(); ... and btw the "CurrentValues" message gets thrown when executing using "OriginalValues" property in entry.OriginalValues.

Comment: That's strange for the error, do you get the same error using my library?

Comment: Hi Jonathan, What are `PreSaveChanges` and `PostSaveChanges`?